# CCSprite texture size

Tags: ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am a bit confused about changing the texture of a CCSprite.

I have:

```
aTexture[NUM_WALLS+11] = [[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"shop1.png"]];
[aSprite setTexture:aTexture[NUM_WALLS+11]];
```

and

```
aTexture[NUM_WALLS+9] = [[CCTexture2D alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bush2.png"]];
[aSprite setTexture:aTexture[NUM_WALLS+9]];
```

The two images have two different sizes.  However, the sprite does NOT change size when I change the texture.  Instead, the image scales to the size of the sprite.  I thought the sprite was supposed to change size.

Can someone please clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The image files may have a different size, but the textures may use the same size since they usually scale up to the next nearest power of two (with NPOT texture support being disabled by default in cocos2d).

Meaning: if one image is 150x150 and the other is 250x250 their textures will both have 256x256 dimensions. If you load a sprite from an image file, cocos2d adjusts the actual part of the texture that is drawn to the size of the image (contentSize). If you change the texture, cocos2d will simply use the size of the texture regardless of the size of the image stored in the texture - because that information is lost after a texture has been created.

In that case you will have to manually call setTextureRect: on the sprite to draw only the area of the actual image in the texture.

The better solution is to [create a texture atlas](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker) with both textures and then just change the sprite frame displayed by the sprite. It's a lot easier and saves memory, too.

Comment: Thanks.  I checked out the cocos2d texture packer tutorial by Ray Wenderlich and a few other sources on the internet.  I am using a grid of a couple hundred sprites in an isometric orientation with monsters and PCs moving around and their is a very z-order dependent situation existing.  I've noticed that I might have issues with z-order during the process of incorporating this into my program.  Since I already have a laboriously constructed and well (still some bugs) interacting system, I think I'll go with your first suggestion  since the cost/benefit ratio for me would be in favor of that.

Answer (score 2):

For those who still want to use setTexture.

I found that this here works:

`CCTexture2D* tex2d =  [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:_texture]];
    CGSize texSize = [tex2d contentSize];
    [sprite setTexture:tex2d];
    [sprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height)];`

the order of setTexture and setTextureRect is important. Otherwise it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i know, CCSprite use it's contentSize property and position to calculate array of vertices to be drawn using OpenGL. In such way, sprite will not change it's vizible size until you change it's contentSize property.

Answer (score 0):

> CCTexture2D* tex2d = [[CCTexture2D alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage
>   imageNamed:_texture]]; CGSize texSize = [tex2d contentSize]; [sprite
>   setTexture:tex2d]; [sprite setTextureRect:CGRectMake(0, 0,
>   texSize.width, texSize.height)];

**WARNING**

This code stores a texture but it may cause a memory leak because the dealloc function is never called.

You can check it by subclassing CCTexture2D class. At least alloc-init always works this wrong way for CCSprite objects